# Is 00 an integer or octal in Java?

Tags: java, integer, octal

Is

> 00, 000, or 000...

an integer in Java? 
Or is it an octal? If is it an octal is

> 001 or 0005

an octal?

Comment: The linked question is about C/C++, not Java! Please reopen it.

Comment: @johnchen902 I actually thought the same, but it looks like the [third answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12276570/2670792) is about Java.

Comment: @Christian That didn't make it a duplicate. I didn't even scroll down that much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**All are integers**, but...

```
1  is decimal
0  is decimal
01 is octal
00 is octal
```

From [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1) (emphasis mine):

> Note that **octal numerals always consist of two or more digits; 0 is always considered to be a decimal numeral** - not that it matters much in practice, for the numerals 0, 00, and 0x0 all represent exactly the same integer value.

Answer (score 4):

Number literal representation examples in Java will give you the answer:

```
int decimal = 100;
int octal = 0144;
int hex = 0x64;
int binary = 0b1100100;
```

So 00, 000 and 0000 are all octal(base-8) integers.

Answer (score 1):

Directly from [specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.1)

> An octal numeral consists of an ASCII digit 0 followed by one or more of the ASCII digits 0 through 7 and **can represent a positive, zero, or negative integer.**

You can check **0 though 7**