# How does Integer.toString in Java exactly work?

Tags: string, tostring

```
public static void main (String[] args) { 
    int a = 0010;
    String num = Integer.toString(a);
    System.out.println(num);    
}
```

Why does it print 8 not 0010?

Comment: Many variations on this question here on SO - see eg http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24031843/is-00-an-integer-or-octal-in-java/24032020#24032020

Comment: possible duplicate of [Integer with leading zeroes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/565634/integer-with-leading-zeroes)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Java interprets integers that start with `0` as being expressed in [octal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Octal).  `10` in octal (base 8) is 8 in decimal (base 10). `Integer.toString()` is doing the correct thing in this case, because the value of `a` is indeed 8.

Answer (score 1):

Integers are stored in binary form in memory. There are several ways to define integer literal. `0010` is octal, in base 8. `toString` prints in base 10 (decimal).